# Connecting through another FTP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ftp, shared-hosting

I have some very large files I'd like to transfer to my new dedicated server from a shared hosting account. I'm wondering if it's possible, using Ubuntu Server, to connect to the other FTP (which allows SSH access as well) and download the files straight to the dedicated server? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: How large is large?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. SSH into the new machine and initiate an [FTP session from the command line](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) and do a `GET` for whatever files you need on the old server.

Comment: I did a little bit more researching. Would this work in my case? http://askubuntu.com/questions/1722/basic-ubuntu-ftp-server

Comment: No, that doesn't apply to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

You probably have `scp`, `rsync` and `ftp` as options to connect to the old server from the new. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to determine the best option given the constraints.

Be sure to keep in mind the bandwidth available to you, being able to resume the transfer following an interruption and whether it may make more sense to copy the data onto a suitable medium (tape, disk, flash, etc.) and mail to your new facility. This option could be less-complex.

Comment: sftp is also likely